# How to disable AppBar shadow when no content is scrolled under it

Tags: flutter

In app_bar.dart file it is mentioned that **elevation** controls the size of the shadow below the app bar and that by default no shadow is drawn if no content is scrolled under the AppBar.

Here is my code :

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    backgroundColor: Colors.grey[50],
    leading: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.menu, color: Colors.blue),
      tooltip: 'Navigation menu',
      onPressed: null,
    ),
    actions: <Widget>[
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.blue,),
        tooltip: 'Search',
        onPressed: null,
      ),
    ],
  ),
  body: listView,
);
```

The shadow is always drawn in my case! Is there a way to fix this or am i doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: what do you have in the body of the scaffold , what you are talking about is not the elevation  of the AppBar

Comment: i've edited my post, and icluded all my code

Comment: take a look at my answer

Comment: If you do nothing, elevation is 4.0 by default. I've had this be the case with nothing but a Container and DecoratedBox under it. If you want to get rid of it completely, just set your elevation to 0.0; if you want it to be conditional, you can use a ternary to set the elevation value depending on your condition or, if you want to get slick and fancy, you can animate the elevation based on a list position, scrollable position or whatever else you want to key an animation controller off of.

Answer (score 6):

To remove the elevation of `AppBar`, simply set `elevation` to 0. If you want to keep elevation while the content scrolled under the `AppBar`, just set `scrolledUnderElevation` a non-zero value. See [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar/scrolledUnderElevation.html).

```dart
AppBar(
    elevation: 0,
    scrolledUnderElevation: 4,
)
```

Comment: This should be accepted! Accomplishes it in a very elegant and simple fashion.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [great article](https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-lets-know-the-scrollcontroller-and-scrollnotification-652b2685a4ac) about this by Diego Velasquez.

Basically what you want is to connect a scrollable listview and an app bar with it's `elevation` value. And when the position of the scrollable is at the "top" - set the elevation value to 0, else to default (4). It's easy to do with a `ScrollController()` widget.

```
//empty_space is a distance of empty padding, only after scrolling through it the content starts getting under the app bar. 
static const double EMPTY_SPACE = 10.0;
ScrollController _controller;
bool isScrolledToTop = true;

@override
  void initState() {
    _controller = ScrollController();
    _controller.addListener(_scrollListener);
    super.initState();
  }

  _scrollListener() {
    if (_scrollController.offset <= _scrollController.position.minScrollExtent &&
        !_scrollController.position.outOfRange) {
      //call setState only when values are about to change
      if(!isScrolledToTop) {
        setState(() {
          //reach the top
          isScrolledToTop = true;
        });
      }

    }else{
      //call setState only when values are about to change
      if(_scrollController.offset > EMPTY_SPACE && isScrolledToTop) {
        setState(() {
          //not the top
          isScrolledToTop = false;
        });
      }
    }
  }

 @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
}
```

now add the controller to your listview, it should look something like this:

```
    ListView.builder(
              controller: _scrollController,
              itemCount: 30,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(title: Text("Index : $index"));
              },
            )
```

and the last step is to show/hide a shadow of the app bar depending on the `isScrolledToTop` flag:

```
appBar: AppBar(
      elevation: isScrolledToTop ? 0 : 4,
      ...,)
```

*IMPORTANT*: I highly recommend to create your AppBar as a standalone widget with its own build() method (`MyAppBar extends StatefulWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget`) and  move `_scrollListener()` method there.

Since the `setState(){}` method forces to rebuild the widget where it was called thus it matters whether you rebuild the entire Page (with the main list view and all its items etc.) or just one single AppBar widget. The latter is significantly cheaper.

If you need more details ping me. Cheers!

Comment: if we move scrollListener/scrollController to separate class, would it be possible to set it to ListView as controller ?

Comment: In this code example, _controller and _scrollController are used for the same variable. Please use only one of them to avoid mistakes when reading the example code.

Answer (score 2):

Actually SliverAppBar uses exactly this behavior of having no shadow when the content is not scrolled below it, and if you want it can even scroll away when you scroll your content. Here's a video explaining how you can use slivers in your Flutter application: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wN2lpqxkB4M

Also if you just want no shadow for the AppBar you can set its elevation property to 0.0, just like this:

```
AppBar(
    elevation: 0.0,
    title: Text("This is my title"),
),
```