# Is there an AppBar in flutter totally dynamic elevation and background color?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to do a dynamic app bar, when the scroll offset of the page is 0, the background color need to be transparent, the logo need to be white and the elevation 0, and, when the scroll offset change from 0, need transition to change the background color to white, the elevation to 5 and the logo color to red

[image: The image when scroll offset is 0]

[image: And here is when scroll offset is greater than 0]

I've already tried this code:

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController = ScrollController()
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {
          offset = _scrollController.offset;
        });
      });
  }

...

final double transitionColor = min(max(offset, 0), 100) / 100;
final double transitionElevation = min(max(offset, 0), 50) / 10;

LjAppBar.getAppBar(
  brandingColor: offset != 0 ? LjTheme.ljPrimary.withOpacity(transitionColor) : Colors.white,
  backgroundColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(transitionColor),
  elevation: transitionElevation,
),
```

But, is so slowly the effects and the application and is not working well... i hope someone can help me

Comment: Please take a look at this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/59533424/10084671

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, the only way you can deal with this is by using [SliverAppBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html). Slivers in Flutter are widgets that can respond dynamically different scrolling statuses. Check out [Slivers, demystified](https://medium.com/flutter/slivers-demystified-6ff68ab0296f) for a nice introduction on the topic from Emily Fortuna from the Flutter team.

In your case, with SliverAppBar, you can change the color, elevation, etc. of your app bar depending on the scrolling of your list. You will need [SliverList](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverList-class.html) for that.

It's kind of difficult to wrap your head around Sliver widgets, but don't get discouraged! Once you get used to them you will be able to achieve what you want.

Comment: Yeaah.. i think use the sliver app bar, but, i can’t used the sliver app bar because im using the stack to scaffold with background image on top and content below the image, i posted in my old question in stackoverflow too, doesn’t have any other way to do this?